# MongoDB Sharding - recent chunks not balanced across shards

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I've recently sharded a replica-set DB to 4 shards, the shard key is `{_id:1}`.
Analyzing recent chunks (5%) distribution across the shards shows the below:

```
db.getCollection('chunks').aggregate([
    {$match: {ns: 'DB.XYZ'}},
    {$sort: {min: -1}},
    {$limit: 2000},
    {$group: {_id: '$shard', sum: {$sum:1}}}
])
```

> {
>       "_id" : "rs1-01",
>       "sum" : 1893.0 }
>
> {
>       "_id" : "rs04",
>       "sum" : 44.0 }
>
> {
>       "_id" : "rs02",
>       "sum" : 28.0 }
>
> {
>       "_id" : "rs03",
>       "sum" : 35.0 }

**Question:** is there an option to distribute the chunks more evenly?

Comment: What kind of values are you using for the `_id` field? Is it the MongoDB generated `ObjectId`?

Comment: It's integer, increased monotonically

Comment: Are you using Ranged or Hashed sharding?

Comment: What's the output of `sh.status()`?

Comment: The shard key is `{_id:1}`, the chunks are well balanced across the shard, the only concern is that recent chunks are mainly in a specific shard